height and non zero divisors
Let $R$ be a polynomial ring $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Suppose $I$ is an $R$-ideal such that $R/I$ is Cohen-Macaulay ring. Let $x$ be a regular element on the ideal $I$ (in other words, $\overline{x}$, the image of $x$ in $R/I$, is a non zero divisor in $R/I$). Does it imply that the height of the ideal $I$ in $R$ and that of $\overline{I}$ in $R/(x)$ are the same?
I believe the ideal $\overline{I}$ in $R/(x)$ is still Cohen-Macaulay, but not sure.

Must a non zero divisor also be a non-unit? If not, assuming $k$ is a field, let $R=k[y]$, $I=(y)$, and let $x$ be any unit of $k$. Then, $R/I = k$ is Cohen-Macaulay, $x$ is still a non-zero divisor on $k$ since $k$ is a domain, but the height of $I$ in $R$ is 1 and the height of the image of $I$ in $R/(x)$ is $0$ since $R/(x)$ is the zero ring.

Or the height of $\overline{I}$ is $-\infty$, or however you want to interpret the height of the zero ideal in the zero ring.

Sorry. It should be a non unit and a non zero divisor.

One idea would be to try and use the Krull height theorem. Can you find an ideal $I$ and element $x$ so that, say, $I$ is 2-generated and height 2, but $\overline{I}$ is principal?

If $x$ is inside $I$, then this is always possible. I am just wondering what happens when $x$ is outside of all the assocaited primes of $I$, (i.e., regular on $I$)

$R=k[X,Y]/(X^2,XY)$, $I=(x,y)$, $a=x+y$. Height of $I$ is one. Height of $\bar I$ in $R/a=k[X]/(X^2)$ is zero since $\dim R/a=0$.

Here $a=x+y$ is not regular over I. In fact $a\in I$.
